# Is there a phantomJS injection vulnerability in page.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, security, phantomjs

Using PhantomJS you can execute code in the browser by doing `page.evaluate()`. Are we opening ourselves up to an attack vector if we allow users to specify code which could be executed in that browser context? Is there a way to escape from the browser context into the phantomJS environment thereby executing commands on our servers?

Here's an example:

```
page.open(options.url, function(status) {
    var test = function() {
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return eval({{USER JAVASCRIPT STRING}});
            });
    });

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (test()) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            // take screenshot, do other stuff, close phantom
          }
        }, 250);
});
```

From my understanding, the `eval()` occuring inside the `page.evaluate()` prevents them from ever escaping the context of the page which was opened. The user javascript string is passed as a string (it is not "compiled" into a single javascript file). It appears to me that it is no different then a user browsing to a site with a browser and attempting to hack away through their favorite Javascript console. Thus, this usage does not represent a security vulnerability. Is this correct?

**Update**

To provide a little more clarity about the exact use case. The basic gist is that someone will go to a url, http://www.myapp.com/?url=http://anotherurl.com/&condition={{javascriptstring}}. When a worker is available, it will spin up a phantom instance, `page.open` the URL provided, and then when `condition` is met, it will take a screenshot of the webpage. The purpose for this is that some pages, especially those with massive amounts of async javascript, have bizarre "ready" conditions that aren't as simple as `DOM ready` or `window ready`. In this way the screenshot won't be taken until a javascript condition is true. Examples include `$(".domNode").data("jQueryUIWidget").loaded == true` or `$(".someNode").length > 0`.

Comment: Sounds right to me. No different than using jsfiddle or something, as long as it's not executed for users other than the script author... but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Wesley Murch  Yes,  except there isn't a session to hijack on jsfiddle...

Comment: @Rook: Right, noted, but as long as the second part is true? I'm not familiar with PhantomJS so cannot comment on *"Is there a way to escape from the browser context into the phantomJS environment thereby executing commands on our servers?"*... We probably need more context from Nucleon here as well.

Comment: @Wesley Murch The point of dom based xss is executing javascript on the browser in the context of the website, which is a nasty vulnerability that can be used to hijack accounts.  Also i updated my post;.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with PhantomJS, but `eval` is inherently unsafe when it comes to running unknown code. It would be very easy to escape the intended context:

```
return page.evaluate(function() {
    return eval({{javascriptstring}});
});
```

> `http://example.com/?url=http://anotherurl.com/&condition={{javascriptstring}}`

How about where `{{javascriptstring}}` equals:

```
console.log('All your script are belong to us');
```

I'm not sure what kind of nasty things you could do with PhantomJS, but it's an example of a user being able to run any code they want, so this doesn't sound like a good idea. The user string could literally be an entire program.

To clarify, the injection vulnerability is not in `page.evaluate()`, it's in the `eval` in *your* code.

Comment: The user string could be an entire program, and that's perfectly OK. From the PhantomJS docs: page.evaluate: `evaluates the given function in the context of the web page. The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom object and it can't probe its own setting.` How does it differ from me going to that URL, and typing `console.log("")` in the window. I can go to any website on the internet and execute an infinite amount of Javascript on it using my browser. But there is no harm because my hacking doesn't interfere or affect any other visitor of that site.

Comment: I'd assume the difference is that: 1) The code is executed on your server, not just the user's browser (right?). If you're OK with letting a user basically paste any code they want into that spot where you do the `eval()`, then I guess that's fine. 2) Related to Rook's answer, if the user can share links with the embedded code (which looks to be the case), then your site can potentially deliver an xss payload. Even something stupid like crashing the user's browser (or locking up their whole system potentially) with `while(1){}` or any other infinite loop, all because of the `eval` function.

Comment: What would an infinite loop do, for example, after I send thousands of requests to a page that will execute it on your server? Or, what's the worst that could happen if you pasted the most malicious code possible into the `page.evaluate` callback? That's what you're allowing. Once again, it's the `eval` bit that's dangerous. I could be missing important details here, so I'm looking forward to your reply because I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  this is [DOM based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  This is a vulnerability that can be used to hijack user's (or administrative) sessions and expose users to other attacks.

If the input comes from a GET/POST or Fragment or part of the URL then its very easy to exploit.  If the input comes from the UI,  then it can be [exploited with clickjacking](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/03/exploiting-unexploitable-xss-with.html).

Comment: only if the page object, or a derivative of it, was shared with another user. right?

Comment: @rambo coder  no,  it has to be accessible via Fragment/URL GET or POST.  So the attacker has to be able to redirect a user to this page.

Comment: @Rook I don't understand. DOM XSS only works if I modify *your* dom. But, if you modify you own DOM, what's the harm in that?

Comment: @Nucleon Where is `{{USER JAVASCRIPT STRING}}` coming from? Is this a GET,  or POST,  or Fragment?  Is it a form on the page?

Comment: Even after your edit I still don't understand the attack vector you are referring to. How can I cause harm to someone else by executing javascript in my own window? Can you provide a concrete example in the phantomjs context which would cause this problem so I can better understand. I do not see the connection between my scenario and XSS/Clickjacking.

Comment: @Nucleon As far as i can tell this is a very serious vulnerability. Perhaps you should familiarize your self with the very basics of xss.  Security is very important and not understanding the threats that we all face will get you fired at best,  at worst you could have a very serious lawsuit on your hands.